# Ionic v2 html not rendering at all (angular 2)

Tags: android, html, angular, typescript, ionic2

My Problem:

I am writing an hybrid app with Ionic v2 and everything worked fine.
I use `ionic serve` and my app just do what it should, so everthing work fine in the browser. But when I run the app on any android phone or the simulator with `ionic run android` I just get a blank screen with no error.

I now tried to remove every new created page and tried to comment all the code but it still just shows me a blank screen.

The weird thing about it is that I just see a blank screen but when I click on a input field (because I know where they are, i cant see them) my device opens the keyboard and I can write.

I even have the

```
cordova camera-preview plugin
```

installed and when I open this one it shows me the Camera but not the user-interface around it.

I just think the HTML is not rendered, but I just can't get it to work.

Ionic events like `onViewDidEnter` is entered and it displays an `alert()`
but all my HTML is not rendered.

I would be glad about every little help

package.json

```
    {
  "name": "ionic-hello-world",
  "author": "Ionic Framework",
  "homepage": "http://ionicframework.com/",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "ionic:build": "ionic-app-scripts build",
    "ionic:serve": "ionic-app-scripts serve"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/common": "2.1.1",
    "@angular/compiler": "2.1.1",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "2.1.1",
    "@angular/core": "2.1.1",
    "@angular/forms": "2.1.1",
    "@angular/http": "2.1.1",
    "@angular/material": "^2.0.0-alpha.10",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "2.1.1",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "2.1.1",
    "@angular/platform-server": "2.1.1",
    "@ionic/storage": "1.1.6",
    "@types/hammerjs": "^2.0.33",
    "ang2-parallax": "^1.0.2",
    "hammerjs": "^2.0.8",
    "ionic-angular": "2.0.0-rc.3",
    "ionic-native": "2.2.3",
    "ionicons": "3.0.0",
    "ng2-progressbar": "^1.0.3",
    "ng2-slim-loading-bar": "^2.0.4",
    "rxjs": "5.0.0-beta.12",
    "zone.js": "0.6.26"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@ionic/app-scripts": "0.0.45",
    "typescript": "2.0.6"
  },
  "cordovaPlugins": [
    "cordova-plugin-whitelist",
    "cordova-plugin-statusbar",
    "cordova-plugin-console",
    "cordova-plugin-device",
    "cordova-plugin-splashscreen",
    "ionic-plugin-keyboard"
  ],
  "cordovaPlatforms": [],
  "description": "An Ionic project"
}
```

Comment: what android versions did you try?

Comment: I used Android **6.0.1**, Android **5.0.2** and Android **4.4**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Error:

I used "too many" variables in an array in an .scss-file.

I have this variable:

`$colors: (
  primary:    #387ef5,
  secondary:  #32db64,
  danger:     #f53d3d,
  light:      #f4f4f4,
  dark:       #222,
  appcolor:   #A717A5,
  tabscolor:  #3441a5,
  progress:   #a90329,
  NAVY-style: #001f3f,
  BLUE-style: #0074D9,
  AQUA-style: #7FDBFF,
  TEAL-style: #39CCCC,
  OLIVE-style:#3D9970,
  GREEN-style:#2ECC40,
  LIME-style: #01FF70,
  YELLOW-style:#FFDC00,
  ORANGE-style:#FF851B,
  RED-style:   #FF4136,
  MAROON-style:#85144b,
  FUCHSIA-style:#F012BE,
  PURPLE-style:#B10DC9,
  BLACK-style:#111111,
  GRAY-style:#AAAAAA,
  SILVER-style:#DDDDDD
  magenta1 :   #EE00EE,
  mediumorchid1: #7A378B,
  slategray1: #6C7B8B,
  skyblue1: #4A708B,
  springgreen1: #008B45,
  darkgreen1: #006400,
  yellow1: #8B8B00,
  warmgrey: #808069,
  orange1: #CD8500,
  lightsalmon1: #8B5742,
  olivedrab1: #8E8E38,
  dark-blue1:      #07064c,
  purplelight1:   #8e50d7,
  purple1:         #8238a3,
  brown1:          #771e10,
  brownorange1:   #e38c2d,
  lightlight1:     #dbdcff,
  darkbrown1:     #230100,
  darkred1:       #8e0400,
  rosa1:           #f6546a,
  militargreen1:   #313304,
  base1:           #baa676,
  skin1:           #c6a339,
  graay1:          #4f5951,
  redlight1:      #853b35,
  weirdgreen1:    #515310,
  weirdergreen1:  #c0bd6b,
  octablue1:       #064a6c,
  hashgray1:       #A9A9A9
);`

And if this $colors-variable contains more than 29 colorvalues, my complete HTML-Rendering is skipped or just don't work. so I am just using a other way to keep this array under 29 elements.

That solved my problem.

Comment: wow..it was a complete misunderstanding of the problem..sorry about that..will delete my answer as it wont help anyone

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your package.json you havent added android platform.
First do

`npm install -g cordova`

**You dont have cordova installed as global**
Then do the below steps.

`ionic platform add android`

An entry will be added in `cordovaPlatforms[]`

Build your app for android before run.

`ionic build android`

Comment: I just removed the platform with `ionic platform remove android` and added it again with `ionic platform add android` and it still just says `cordovaPlatforms[]` in my `package.json`

Comment: try `ionic platform add android --save`

Comment: do you have android in platforms folder?

Comment: yeah i have. the folder is present. I removed and added it again at its still `cordovaPlatforms[]`. I did `ionic run android` and the screen is still blank..

Comment: try `ionic platforms` . what is the output?

Comment: do `ionic build android` before run.

Comment: this is the output `ionic platforms`:



`Installed platforms:
  android 6.0.0
Available platforms:
  amazon-fireos ~3.6.3 (deprecated)
  blackberry10 ~3.8.0
  browser ~4.1.0
  firefoxos ~3.6.3
  webos ~3.7.0
  windows ~4.4.0
  wp8 ~3.8.2 (deprecated)
`

Comment: ok..for some reason it is not updating package.json..is it building?

Comment: after building and then manually installing apk on the phone, it still dont work..

Comment: not one... but the project worked before so maybe ionic updated itself and maybe the update is not working and displaying an error

Comment: what is your ionic cli version

Comment: `$ ionic info`
`******************************************************
 Dependency warning - for the CLI to run correctly,
 it is highly recommended to install/upgrade the following:

 Please install your Cordova CLI to version  >=4.2.0 `npm install -g cordova`

******************************************************`

Comment: `Your system information:

 You have been opted out of telemetry. To change this, run: cordova telemetry on.
6.4.0

Ionic Framework Version: 2.0.0-rc.3
Ionic CLI Version: 2.1.12
Ionic App Lib Version: 2.1.7
Ionic App Scripts Version: 0.0.45
ios-deploy version: Not installed
ios-sim version: Not installed
OS: Windows 7
Node Version: v6.9.1
Xcode version: Not installed`

Comment: install cordova.. whenever you install fresh ionic you do `npm install -g cordova ionic`

Comment: I updated my cordova and Ionic version but I got this warnings at the beginning: `npm WARN deprecated node-uuid@1.4.7: use uuid module instead
npm WARN deprecated minimatch@0.2.14: Please update to minimatch 3.0.2 or higher to avoid a RegExp DoS issue
npm WARN deprecated minimatch@0.3.0: Please update to minimatch 3.0.2 or higher to avoid a RegExp DoS issue
npm WARN deprecated minimatch@2.0.10: Please update to minimatch 3.0.2 or higher to avoid a RegExp DoS issue
npm WARN deprecated node-uuid@1.3.3: use uuid module instead`

Comment: they dont matter.. thats fine

Comment: and this warnings at the end of the install: `npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@^1.0.0 (node_modules\ionic\node_modules\chokidar\node_modules\fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@1.0.17: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"win32","arch":"x64"})
npm WARN In ionic@2.1.18 replacing bundled version of mime-types with mime-types@2.0.14
npm WARN In ionic@2.1.18 replacing bundled version of cross-spawn with cross-spawn@4.0.2
`

Comment: and this:`npm WARN In ionic@2.1.18 replacing bundled version of semver with semver@4.2.0
npm WARN In ionic@2.1.18 replacing bundled version of form-data with form-data@0.2.0
npm WARN In ionic@2.1.18 replacing bundled version of request with request@2.51.0
npm WARN In ionic@2.1.18 replacing bundled version of ionic-app-lib with ionic-app-lib@2.1.9`

Comment: and it still gives me this:
`******************************************************
 Dependency warning - for the CLI to run correctly,
 it is highly recommended to install/upgrade the following:

 Please install your Cordova CLI to version  >=4.2.0 `npm install -g cordova`

******************************************************`

Comment: what is output of `cordova -v`

Comment: `$ cordova -v

You have been opted out of telemetry. To change this, run: cordova telemetry on.
6.4.0`